# Creating a GCD queue for a specific NSThread

Tags: multithreading, opengl, grand-central-dispatch, cgcontext, nsthread

I would like to create a thread for offline rendering with its own OpenGL context.

For submitting rendering tasks, I would like to use GCD, due to its API simplicity.

Is it possible to create a GCD queue that is attached to a specific NSThread (which has its own OpenGL context)?

It seems to be possible, since the main queue always runs it tasks on the main thread, but I could not find anything with similar behavior for custom threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current context at the beginning of every task, as described here: ["OpenGL Restricts Each Context to a Single Thread"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/opengl-macprogguide/opengl_threading/opengl_threading.html).

You can also set a context for the dispatch queue, as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW13).